# How to create a custom audience using facebook api and sandbox ad account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create a custom audience using sandbox ad account. Following request:

```
curl \
 -F 'name=My new CA' \
 -F 'subtype=CUSTOM' \
 -F 'description=People who bought from my website' \
 -F 'access_token=<<my_token>>' \
 https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_<<my_account_id>>/customaudiences
```

fails with:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#2655) Terms of service has not been accepted. To accept, go to https://www.facebook.com/ads/manage/customaudiences/tos.php?act=<<my_account_id>>",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 2655
  }
}
```

But the link with Terms of service page is invalid. Moreover, I cannot accept ToS using Ads Manager, because only non sandbox account are available there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facebook has updated sandbox ad account management and it is now possible to add use custom audiences in sandbox mode. To accept custom audiences ToS go to the application management -> Marketing API -> Tools -> Sandbox Ad Account Management -> Actions -> Accept TOS

Comment: I have already done this.. Under Sandbox Ad Account Management -> Actions, I can see a tick mark against the `Accept TOS` icon. But when I try to create custom audiences, I still get the error "Custom Audience Terms Not Accepted"

Comment: same problem here too

Comment: @tmueller my problem is resolved by creating a system user. I add the system user as app admin and add the ad account to the system user. Then I created the access token for the system user and it worked. Hope it works for you too

Comment: @small_ticket Still dealing with the same issue. Created a system user in the business manager. Assigned the system user to the ad account (in Tools -> Sandbox). Made the system user an app admin. Used the system user's token with all ad related permissions. But still getting the same response. Is this what you are describing?

Comment: @small_ticket How to add sandbox account to the system user. When i try to add sandbox account to my business, i get this error: This business has a pending ownership request to this object. Please cancel or decline it to continue. But i dont know where to accept that.

Comment: @NelsonSequiera I answered wrongly before now I get it. I'm not creating a Sandbox account. I could not make it work with the Sandbox account. I tried with a real one.

Comment: @tmueller I'm sorry I missed a point in your comment. I did not work with the Sandbox account. I could not mannage to make it work with it. I tried with a regular account. Maybe it helps.

Comment: @small_ticket oh. even i had issues with real ad account. But managed to solve it. But stuck with sandbox account ToS.

Comment: Since I just ran into this issue as well, according to this ticket https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/2283053638576438/ the only way to link a sandbox account with a page is with a verified business account. If you created a fake business account like I did, you won’t be able to add a custom audience unless you go through the real verification process.