# is it allowed to create a web custom audience in facebook ads sdk v2.8 in sandbox?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

I know there's already a version 2.9 of the facebook marketing api, but am still currently using the v2.8, and I am running calls using the sandbox. now my question is, are we allowed to create web custom audience in the sandbox ? I tried to run this snippet in the facebook graph explorer

```
act_<ACCOUNT ID>/?fields=tos_accepted
```

I got this result for my sandbox account

```
{
  "tos_accepted": {
    "custom_audience_tos": 1
  },
  "id": "act_<my account id>"
}
```

but when I tried to run the same query using a non-sandbox account, I got different result

```
{
  "tos_accepted": {
    "custom_audience_tos": 1,
    "web_custom_audience_tos": 1
  },
  "id": "act_<my account id>"
}
```

you see the web_custom_audience_tos property is not in the output when I used a sandbox account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can create Website Custom Audiences (WCA) using the Sandbox, however you will need to accept the terms & conditions for this.

If you try to create a WCA without accepting them, you'll get something like this:

`{"error":{"message":"(#2663) Terms of service has not been accepted. To accept, go to https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/customaudiences\/app\/tos\/?act=ACCOUNT_ID","type":"OAuthException","code":2663,"fbtrace_id":""}}`

To accept the TOS, you can go here, replacing the act ID with your Sandbox ID:

https://www.facebook.com/customaudiences/app/tos/?act=12312312

Comment: that url (replaced with my account id)..always says expired...i don't know if it's because of the sandbox or what...but in real account, i never seen an expired tos url

Comment: if you try to make the request yourself, it'll give you the URL you need to go to.

Comment: by the way, I need help..can you accept me in the facebook developer community?..i know it's not your job to do it..but i dunno why is it that whenever I request to join, the button  on my account resets back to join instead of pending, I'm not even using a fake account to request in joining..(because it's hard to get help in stackoverflow that has something to do with facebook apis )...the name is marvin

Comment: I'm not in that group unfortunately!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Sandbox account for testing, and are getting this TOS error, you will need to follow these steps: 
(which I got from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42766604/544130)

> To accept custom audiences ToS go to the application management ->
>   Marketing API -> Tools -> Sandbox Ad Account Management -> Actions ->
>   Accept TOS