# Facebook - custom audience ToS for sandbox account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im trying to create custom audience using API. With the live ad account this works, but with **sandbox account** i get the below error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Permissions error",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 200,
        "error_subcode": 1870034,
        "is_transient": false,
        "error_user_title": "Custom Audience Terms Not Accepted",
        "error_user_msg": "You'll need to agree to the Custom Audience terms before you can create or edit an audience of CUSTOM type. To accept, go to https://www.facebook.com/ads/manage/customaudiences/tos/?act=************.",
        "fbtrace_id": "********"
    }
}
```

When i goto the URL provided, it tells me:

> The link you followed may have expired, or the page may only be visible to an audience you're not in.

I have accepted ToS in marketing app tools as well.

I have added system user to the business, made system user as app admin for the app.

When i check for accepted ToS, i get this:

```
{
    "tos_accepted": {
        "web_custom_audience_tos": 1
    },
    "id": "act_***********"
}
```

I have looked at following answers, but still getting error:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42766604/5690875

Am I missing any step?

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same issue. So far I couldn't manage to get those Custom Audience ToS properly accepted by the sandbox Ad Account.

What did work for me was to create some dummy accounts and apps so I could use the API and test my code.

For now I did open a bug https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/370563156815064 and if there is any update I will update my answer here too.

Also there is another very similar bug already open https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/229033267958911. In the comments Felix(the guy who opened the bug) says that he managed to login with the sandbox Ad Account and accept the terms. I do not know how would you login with a sandbox Ad Account, but I did not look into it either.