# Creating a Facebook Ad Account Sandbox account and unlocking ads_read - (AKA: Getting through the getting started tutorial from facebook)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

*I apologise in advance if this question has been asked elsewhere or if it's a stupid question, but I'm desperate!*

**My goal**

Create a POC which connects to a facebook sandbox ad account and tests what features are exposed in the API, such as uploading new video ads or creating ad campaigns.

**The problem**

I am following facebooks own getting started example for connecting with nodejs:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/business-sdk/getting-started/#js

When i try to read from the AdAccount i get the following error:
`(#278) Reading advertisements requires an access token with the extended permission ads_read`

Under Marketing API -> Settings, it is possible to submit a request to be granted access. I think..? This part confuses me a lot.
In order for me to grant my access token the right to make calls requiring the `ads_read` permission, a human person at facebook must first grant me the right to grant this right to my access token?? (Please tell me if I got this wrong, it feels like that has to be wrong).

**Chicken and the Egg?**

As part of this proces i have to provide detailed instructions on reproducing the required need for permissions and a screencast of the process.

However all i have at this point is the sample code provided by facebooks example. And i don't plan on developing anything for this until i can at least get their sample working, which i can't without being granted access to `ads_read` it would seem.

**I must have misunderstood something**

It seems obvious that i must have misunderstood something, but what?

- Am i not supposed to follow the example from facebook called getting started? I that not the right example for getting started?
- Or am I trying to unlock the permission in the wrong place?
- Is the error just misleading?
- Or should i just complete the submission steps for ads_read and provide an empty screencast and say I'm just getting started?

Any help, clues, or link to guides that address this issue would be greatly appreciated. (Again i apologise if this question is very basic but I'm at the end of my rope here, thanks in advance)

Comment: You should configure the required permission of your created app in the marketing api tool section, check the url like: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<APP-ID>/marketing-api/tools/

Comment: I tried to get this working all day and 10 mins after i post the question i found the issue. The URL you posted is where I found a button called 'connect-to-business' which i could have sworn wasn't there earlier (Maybe i didn't have a business at the time). It had me create a user, link it to the business and link that to the sandbox account and then create a token for the user with explicit permissions. I'm done for today but I'll try to post a full guide on how to get the correct token to make the getting started sample work. If I can manage to make it though that maze once again. Thank you

Comment: I'm just getting started with `marketing-api` & *Sandbox Ad Account* appears *overpromised and underdelivered*. Guides / documentation are scarce, there's no shortage of issues ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61728093/3679900), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60977462/3679900), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40468891/3679900), [link4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52336814/3679900)) and community support is [puny](https://developers.facebook.com/community/search?text=marketing-api)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In case anyone else is having the same problem i was, I feel it's appropriate to post how I managed to get the right token.

First off there is nothing wrong with the tutorial code here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/business-sdk/getting-started/#js

The hard part is to find the right token and give it access to make the calls used in the tutorial.

Assuming that you already have managed to create a Sandbox Ad Account you need to connect it to your business account here:
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[APP-ID]/marketing-api/tools/?business_id=[BUSINESS-ID]

On this page there should be 4 buttons next to where the sandbox account is listed. One of them is a key with the caption "Get Access Token". This is the WRONG access token. (If anyone can elaborate on how/why please feel free).
In order to get the access token you need to run the "Getting Started" sample you will need the ads_read permission.

Among the 4 buttons there should also be a suitcase with the caption "Connect to Business". If you do not see this button it either means you have no business or that you haven't attached a system user to your business (I think).

**If the button is not there**
Go to: https://business.facebook.com/settings/system-users?business_id=[BUSINESS-ID]
Create a system user and connect it to your App. Don't forget to set the permissions for that user.

**If the button is there**
Click the button and select your system user in the dropdown.
Then go to:
https://business.facebook.com/settings/system-users/[SYSTEM-USER-ID]?business_id=[BUSINESS-ID]

And click the Generate New Token button. Again don't forget to set the permissions for the token.

It may seem like a silly issue but it cost me almost a whole day myself so hopefully this could save someone else the time.

**EDIT:** I came across an access token debugger which could prove helpful to others with access token problems:
 https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: yes! This worked for me! BTW, this whole process is such a complicated disaster! Took me a long time to find this post as well!

Comment: I keep getting an oops message at the popup of Connecting Sandbox Ad Account to Your Business. Any idea why? I have followed and generated all tokes

Comment: @Jalpesh It's hard for me to speculate with only "oops message" to go on. If you post the full error message in a comment, or create a new question, then someone may be able to help.

Comment: Actually here are more details of the issue
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/642464889620108/

If you check the screenshot attached, you will see the UI message only says oops and nothing more. I checked my network console, and did not get any other error.

Comment: Regarding the "oops message": disabling my ad-blocker (and in Firefox, the activity blocker) did the trick. I manage to connect my sandbox account with my business. This also allowed other parts in Business Manager to work.

Comment: for anyone following this issue Facebook support closed the aforementioned bug report and a new one was opened (w/o a solution yet) here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/2859862384334378/?join_id=f30d80c2a741288

Answer (score 0):

Its in your app tools at the url https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APPID/marketing-api/tools/

If you don't have an app, create a test app