# Facebook throwing strange error when attempting to create custom audience with sandbox ad account

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-custom-audience

My team has had a FB marketing/business account for 2 years now, and we opened our sandbox account around that time. However, when I run my script to create an audience for the sandbox account, I receive this error:

```
status: 400,
  response: {
    error: {
      message: '(#2654) Customer List Audiences Are Not Available: Ad accounts owned by businesses new to Facebook Products can create customer file Custom Audiences after several weeks of following our policies.',
      type: 'OAuthException',
      code: 2654,
      error_subcode: 1870054,
      fbtrace_id: '*****'
    }
  },
```

I've accepted the ToS as many answers have previously suggested. I've been able to populate the sandbox with other data, but creating an audience is giving me serious problems. If anyone has run into this issue or has any suggestions, I'd really appreciate the feedback.

Comment: i get same error when I try to share a custom audience to another Business `Ad accounts owned by businesses new to Facebook Products can share customer file .. after several weeks of following our policies.`

Comment: I've created [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61755399/3679900) along your lines

Comment: Hi @y2k-shubham did you manage to solve this? How?

Comment: unfortunately no. I posted it on [FB developer forums](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/186751512451508/?post_id=186751515784841) too but got no response. Due to this and several other similar issues of lack of clarity, we decided to abandon our efforts in building a wrapper over FB's ad-console.